# Integral involving the gamma function

Tags: prime-numbers, integration, gamma-function

If we define $$f(x) = 1 + \frac{\cos\big(\pi\frac{\Gamma(x) + 1}{x}\big)}{2 - \cos(2\pi{x})}$$ how would one go about evaluating
$$ \int_1^R \frac{1}{x} \log{f(xe^{i\alpha})} dx$$ for some parameter angle $\alpha$ and an arbitrarily large $R$?  I know I'm supposed to show some progress but I really have no idea how to do this - I posted this on math.stackexchange and got no responses.

Edit: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621528/integral-involving-the-gamma-function) is a link to my Stack Exchange question.

Edit: We can assume $\alpha$ to be small.

Comment: Please provide a link to your MSE question.

Comment: have you tried evaluating it numerically? this may give you some idea on interesting parameter regimes --- some simple formula that evaluates the integral exactly is unlikely.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks! What numerical integration methods would you recommend for an integral of this type?

Comment: Given that $f(x)$ will blow up at the points where $\cos(2\pi x e^{i\alpha})=2$, are you sure there is a well-defined branch of the logarithm for the purposes of this integral?

Comment: We can assume $\alpha$ to be small, so it shouldn't be a problem. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: There are points with $\cos(2\pi xe^{i\alpha})=2$ for arbitrarily small $\alpha$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay will it necessarily make the integral divergent? The problem, in some sense, involves taking the limit as $\alpha$ goes to $0$, but that seems to still include the poles...

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you come across this integral?

Comment: I don't know. The prospect of the real part of the argument of the logarithm suddenly flicking from large positive to large negative isn't pretty.  On the other hand, the cosine is only 2 at isolated points so you could just require that the ray misses them.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay as $\alpha$ goes to $0$ the real part should go to 0 too, so the imaginary part is more important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand that the OP is after the imaginary part of the integral in the small-$\alpha$ limit. To evaluate this limit, I note that [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) implies that, for real positive $x$, the function
$$f(x) = 1 + \frac{\cos\big(\pi\frac{\Gamma(x) + 1}{x}\big)}{2 - \cos(2\pi{x})}=0\;\;{\rm iff}\;x\;\text{is a prime integer},$$ 
so the imaginary part of $\log f(x+i0^+)$ is a step function of $x$, increasing by $\pi$ at each prime, as the logarithm winds through its branches:
$$\lim_{\alpha\downarrow 0}\,{\rm Im}\,\log f(xe^{i\alpha})=\pi\times\text{number of primes smaller than}\; x.$$
The integral then evaluates in the desired limit to
$$\lim_{\alpha\downarrow 0}\,{\rm Im}\,\int_1^R \frac{1}{x}\log f(xe^{i\alpha})\,dx=\sum_{{\rm primes}\, p<R}\pi\log(R/p).$$

I am surprised to conclude that this integral sums over primes, but I guess that was the context in which it appeared, am I right? [I took the liberty of adding the "prime-numbers" tag to the question.]

Comment: You're right, that is where I encountered the problem. Also, do you think a numerical evaluation of this integral could yield better bounds on functions relating to primes?

Comment: I would think this integral is just Wilson's theorem in disguise, which is known to be of no use computationally.

Comment: That makes sense, but I was thinking more about bounds on functions such as the prime-counting function and the Chebyshev Functions. Would numerical evaluation of this (in terms of R) possibly help evaluate those?